# Grub2 doesn't recognize any new partitions?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, filesystem, bootloader

I am trying to add a new partition to my drive. The drive contains files that grub can boot into (Live ISOs, or Windows Installers). My drive has 250 GB unallocated and has in the past.. Grub2 booted just fine.

When attempting to boot from the new partition I get `Error: unknown filesystem`. Using ls on the partition (`ls (hd0,msdos5)`) still tells me the partition is unknown, while using ls can see the older partitions. I have tried formatting the empty space to FAT32 and NTFS. Same result. Make the partitions smaller or larger in size doesn't make a difference either.

Anyone know why or how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Post this: `sudo parted -l` Grub does not automatically loopmount ISO. You have to manually add your own entries in 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey there i too experienced with such problem once but instead of formatting free space you need to format complete hdd{so sorry to say that :( }

Because any hdd will have only 4 primary partitions on which any operting system can be installled to be seen in boot loader (grub or burg etc...)

so according to my knowledge and experience take backup and "clean" (windows command) it and reinstall all other operating systems that you have installed.

if there is another best way please let me know.

Comment: Just to understand.. are you saying I can have only a maximum of four operating systems installed (no live versions) on a bootloader?